# Hint proving this $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}k=n2^{2n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I need hint proving this $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}k=n2^{2n-1}$$

Comment: Why do you believe this to be true?

Comment: Sorry,I missed $k$. edited

Comment: try double counting. One way of doing this is to think of the left hand side as the number of ways of picking $k$ people from $2n$ and then choosing a "leader"

Comment: Algebraically, just use $$k\binom{2n}{k} =2n \binom{2n-1}{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the identity $k\dbinom{n}k=n\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}kk=2n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-1}{k-1}=2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}k\;.$$

Then note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{2n-1-k}=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}k\;,$$

and

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}k+\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}k=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}k\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}k=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}k\;.$$

Can you finish the proof from here?

**Added:** Alternatively, you can use the first identity to rewrite the desired result as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}k=2^{2n-2}$$

and get there even quicker.

Answer (score 5):

A different solution. The left hand side is the number of ways to pick any number of students between $0$ and $n$ and then picking one to be the "leader." To show this equal to the right hand side, note that we can pick a leader first, giving $2n$ choices, and then for the remaining $2n-1$ people, each can either be in the group or not, which gives $2^{2n-1}.$

The point now is that for the remaining $2n-1$ people, any group which takes $k\le n-1$ of them has a corresponding complement which takes $2n-1 - k \ge n$ of them, so exactly half of these groups have at most $n$ people, giving the desired $n\cdot 2^{2n-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate that sum, consider

$\sum_{k=0}n \binom{2n}{k} x^k.$ If This is half of the sum from $0$ to $2n,$ which is equal to $(1+x)^{2n}.$ To get the $k$ term,integrate the previous sum with respect to $x,$ and see what happens.

Comment: why is this half of the sum? he is also multiplying by $k$ so you can't use a symmetry argument. to be clear, this is true, but not immediately obvious

Comment: @lyj I am out of it today, I have edited the answer to say what I meant to say.