# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \binom{2n}{k} \cdot k = 2^{2n -1} \cdot n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \binom{2n}{k} \cdot k = 2^{2n -1} \cdot n$.

What I know is that $\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \binom{n}{k} \cdot k = 2^{n -1} \cdot n$.

How do I proceed from there?

Comment: Do you know how to prove the identity that you already know?

Comment: Yes I do. It looks so similar, but I really don't know how to deduce the unknown equation from it.

Comment: It's more that the same proof technique works for both of them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hint proving this $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}k=n2^{2n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605908/hint-proving-this-sum-k-0n-binom2nkk-n22n-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{2n}{k} 
&= \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{2n}{k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n 2n\binom{2n-1}{k-1} \\
&= n \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\binom{2n-1}{k-1} + \binom{2n-1}{k-1}\right) \\
&= n \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\binom{2n-1}{k-1} + \binom{2n-1}{2n-k}\right) \\
&= n \sum_{j=0}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{j} \\
&= n \cdot 2^{2n-1}
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, a combinatorial proof is to count the number of committees of size at most $n$ with one chairperson from $2n$ people.  The LHS conditions on the size $k$ of the committee.  The RHS selects the chairperson (in $2n$ ways) and then any subset of size at most $n-1$ from the remaining $2n-1$ people (to see that there are $2^{2n-1}/2$ of these, consider complementary pairs).

Comment: If $k$ is allowed to vary from $0$ to $n$, the largest committee that could be formed has size $n$.

Comment: Thank you guys for the great explanation. That equality from the third to second last equality was what I always kept overlooking. I knew this somehow had to be very easy.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\dbinom{2n}{0}+\dbinom{2n}{1}+\dbinom{2n}{2}+...+\dbinom{2n}{2n-1}+\dbinom{2n}{2n}=2^{2n}$$

$$\dbinom{2n}{0}+\dbinom{2n}{1}+\dbinom{2n}{2}+...+\dbinom{2n}{n-1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}=2^{2n-1}$$

$$\dbinom{n}{k}=\dbinom{n}{n-k}$$

$$k\dbinom{n}{k}+(n-k)\dbinom{n}{n-k}=n\dbinom{n}{k}$$

$$0\dbinom{2n}{0}+1\dbinom{2n}{1}+2\dbinom{2n}{2}+...+(2n-1)\dbinom{2n}{2n-1}+2n\dbinom{2n}{2n}=2n\dbinom{2n}{0}+2n\dbinom{2n}{1}+2n\dbinom{2n}{2}+...+2n\dbinom{2n}{n-1}+2n\dbinom{2n}{n}=2n(\dbinom{2n}{0}+\dbinom{2n}{1}+\dbinom{2n}{2}+...+\dbinom{2n}{n-1}+\dbinom{2n}{n})=2n\times 2^{2n-1}$$

Hence

$$n\dbinom{2n}{0}+n\dbinom{2n}{1}+n\dbinom{2n}{2}+...+n\dbinom{2n}{n-1}+n\dbinom{2n}{n}=n\times2^{2n-1}$$

Comment: If you use double dollar signs (`$$...$$`) rather than single (`$...$`) for your math, you get many benefits: 1) automatic displaystyle, so no need to use `\dbinom`, you can just use `\binom` 2) center alignment, and 3) new line with double backslashes.

Comment: @Arthur : Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n \choose k}k = 2^{2n -1}\,\,n}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n \choose k}k} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{\pars{2n}! \over  \pars{k - 1}!\pars{2n - k}!}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
{\pars{2n}! \over  k!\pars{2n - k - 1}!} =
\color{red}{2n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{2n - 1 \choose  k}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2n\
\underbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{2n - 1}{2n - 1 \choose  k}}
_{\ds{2^{2n - 1}}}\ -\
2n\sum_{k = n}^{2n - 1}{2n - 1 \choose  k}
\\[5mm] = &\
2^{2n}\,n - 2n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{2n - 1 \choose  k + n}
=
2^{2n}\,n -
2n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{2n - 1 \choose  n - 1 - k}
\\[5mm] = &\
2^{2n}\,n -
\color{red}{2n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
{2n - 1 \choose  k}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n \choose k}k} = \color{red}{2n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
{2n - 1 \choose  k}} = 
{2^{2n}\,n \over 2} = \bbx{2^{2n - 1}\,n} \\ &
\end{align}