# finding a closed formula for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{2n \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

my attempt:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{2n \choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} k{2n \choose k}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} k{2n \choose k}$

**the first term in the right hand side**

suppose there are  $2n$ poeple, we have to choose a community from them ,and then we have to choose a president from the community chosen ,so if we choose 1 people then there is one possiblity for choose the president ,and if we choose 2 people then there are two possibility for choose the president,and so on,so all ways possible is $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} k{2n \choose k}$,and we can do it by an other way; we can choose $1$ person from them and then we have to choose a community from the remaining $2n-1$;the numbers of ways to do it,is;${2n \choose 1} 2^{2n-1}$

**the second term in the right hand side**

suppose there are  $2n$ poeple, we have to choose a community from them but thier members doesnot less than  $n+1$ people  ,and then we have to choose a president from the community chosen ,so if we choose $n+1$ people then there is $n+1$ possiblity for choose the president,and so on,so all ways possible is $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} k{2n \choose k}$and we can do it by an other way;we can choose $n+1$ people from $2n$ and,and choose a president from those $n+1$ people  then we have to choose a community from the remaining ,that's means;$(n+1){2n \choose n+1} 2^{2n-(n-1)}=(n+1){2n \choose n+1} 2^{n-1}$

so finally;$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k{2n \choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} k{2n \choose k}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} k{2n \choose k}$

$={2n \choose 1} 2^{2n-1}-(n+1){2n \choose n+1} 2^{n-1}$

does my attempt correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605908/hint-proving-this-sum-k-0n-binom2nkk-n22n-1

Comment: my solution is different

Comment: Numerical calculations suggest that the two are different.

Comment: yeah just i want to know where is the mistake in my attempt

Comment: your value of $~\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} k \cdot {2n \choose k}$ is wrong and how did you get that?

Comment: That is not the what the combinatorial proof is for, @MathLover, the idea is to split it into two sums, each of which can be simplified nicely with a combinatorial proof. The final answer they reached is at the end. The problem seems to be a double counting argument in the simplification of the second sum.

Comment: @person the argument for the second term on RHS is completely flawed and my simple point is that if you can make that argument for the second term on RHS, why not find a way to make that argument for the LHS itself? After all if you choose $n$ people or more from $2n$, you could as well choose from the remaining people who are $n$ or less.

Comment: @math lover , did you can find a way to make that argument for the LHS itself,and does this methode   is easy than what i did?

Comment: already i tried  to did what you say ,but i think it is not easy

Comment: Yes the LHS argument is simple - it is same as the second answer

Comment: I would be grateful if you would post it as another answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinatorics are not my strong suite, but I believe the issue lies with your second method for choosing a set of more than $n+1$ from $2n$, where you possibly double count.

You first choose $n+1$ people, then choose a president from this set, then choose additional people to add on. But consider the set $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, choosing $\{a,b,c,f\}$ with $a$ as president and $\{a,b,d,f\}$ with $a$ as president are covered as separate cases in the first two choices. But then they are counted as the same choice if the additional people are chosen as $\{d,e\}$ and $\{c,e\}$ respectively.

Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to mend your argument to finish the proof. Perhaps someone else can figure something out?

Comment: Exactly. Well spotted

Comment: very nice, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

@person has found the flaw. Let's fix it

In the second scenario, we can choose the president among the $2n$ people, and afterwards choose a set of at least $n$ members from the remainin $2n-1$ . The counting is

$$ 2n \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}$$

But the sum, is $$  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k} = 2^{2n-2}$$

(This can also be seen considering that each choosing of at least $n$ members out of $2n-1$ maps one to one to the complementary choosing of less than $n$ members)

Hence the final result is

$$ 2n 2^{2n-1} - 2n 2^{2n-2} = n 2^{2n-1}$$

Comment: thank you......

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the argument that you are making for the second term of RHS can directly be made for the LHS.

The LHS is equivalent to first choosing a president from $2n$ people and then choosing $(n-1)$ regular members on the committee from remaining $(2n-1)$ people.

$ \displaystyle \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot \binom{2n}{k} = 2n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k} = 2n \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}$

So,

$ \displaystyle \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot \binom{2n}{k} = n \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}$

Now for $~ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}~$, you can either directly use the known identity from binomial theorem or use a combinatorial proof. The expression is equivalent to choosing  members for a committee and number of members can vary from $0$ to $(2n-1)$. That is equivalent to exercising two choices for each of $(2n-1)$ people - either they are in the committee or they are not and that is $2^{2n-1}$.

That leads to answer $~n \cdot 2^{2n-1}$.

Comment: nice thank you.